# Clustering approaches/algorithms for datetime data with categorical dtypes

Tags: python, time-series, cluster-analysis, categorical-data

I have a large dataset with around 200 features, consisting mostly of dates and categorical data, with some continuous features. The dataset is extracted from a postal service. Small example:

I tried to make the example as general as possible, for futures reference. These are selected (scrambled) entries for context:

```
  shipment        delivery          cost        time        location                weight_kg

 2020-04-22      2020-04-27         77.31     19:42:00     UK:66c54f531....           0.5
 2020-04-22      2020-04-25         44.14     19:42:00     DK:22c54f531....           2.23
 2020-04-24      2020-04-24         53.84     09:55:00     UK:66c54f531....           1.57 
 2020-04-24      2020-04-26         22.09     14:27:00     UK:66c54f531....           1.2
```

My first inclination was to make a demand-forecast model on shipment/count_monthly(shipment), but considering the amount of features, a multivariate case seemed more relevant. I am just not sure which additional features to add - and more importantly - such that this project does become to generic (linear regression). Mine initial EDA depicted variables with low correlation, and are removed otherwise to avoid multicollinearity.

- Then, instead I considered a clustering approach, to gather relations between the features in more detail. Just not sure how to approach it with such a large data size and with what seems like timeseries data, never really worked with that dtype before.

I say seemingly, as I understand that timeseries data must be chronological and without duplicates, which the above date columns (shipment/delivery) have.

- So, should I rather regard the date columns as categories? Even if some of the features are timeseries (the time column).

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry but I can't say much regarding your question whether you should transform the date columns to categories, because I have never tried this before. However, I wouldn't categorize (e.g. encode) the dates as categorical features because that would mean that every date would be a single category on its own. It may be better to subset the dates to months and encode the months in twelve categories (but be carefull for high-cardinality) or maybe seasons (winter, spring, summer, autumn).

Nonetheless, the goal of my answer below is to make you think about whether you actually need to perform clustering to solve your project question, before you start thinking about the required data transformations. I hope you and everyone else who reads this appreciates this attempt:

The main questions you should ask yourself are:

1. What are you aiming to get from your clustering analysis?
2. Will clustering analysis help you achieve this aim?

I cannot answer these questions for you, because I don’t know your project well enough. However, here are my two cents on some of the challenges surrounding clustering.

One of the main challenges with clustering analysis is the way you define similarity in your dataset. This becomes increasingly challenging if you have mixed datatype datasets which is true in your case (categorical and continuous features). I know several distance or similarity matrices have been proposed to combine continuous and categorical features (e.g. Gower's distance matrix and Unsupervised RandomForest).

Let's say you successfully created a mixed datatype distance matrix. Then the next question becomes which clustering algorithm will you use? Quite often the more traditional (hard)-clustering algorithms (K-means, hierarchical clustering etc.) are listed due to their computational efficiency and relatively intuitive mechanisms. However, these approaches are also heuristic in their nature. For example, it is difficult to pick the correct cut-off when there are two or more partitions with similar dendrogram-cutting thresholds in hierarchical clustering or silhouette scores in K-methods. I am also unaware of an alternative (e.g. statistically sound) goodness-of-fit measure for these clustering approaches. Moreover, these traditional clustering methods will  **always** identify clusters, even when there are none in reality.

The aim of a clustering analysis is quite often to find the 'common denominators' that define cluster membership. Again, how will you evaluate the correctness of the partitions and their respective characteristics, because the correct partitions are not known (otherwise you wouldn't perform clustering in the first place)? This is even more troublesome when you have heterogenous data that doesn't separate well, because there is a fair chance that different algorithms will identify different clusters within the same dataset. Which algorithm did then identify the correct cluster?

One way to (partly) overcome these challenges is (mixed) model-based clustering, but this can be computationally expensive and a challenge to implement in Python. I think there are a few model-based clustering packages in R that allow the use of mixed datatype datasets (e.g. `mclust`), but I have not used these extensively nor have I studied their papers.

P.S. I do think this question (or my answer) was maybe more suited for Cross Validated, because that platform focuses more on the theoretical principles of data-driven methods.

*Some literature that I found interesting on the challenges surrounding clustering:

Luxburg Uv, Williamson RC, Guyon I. Clustering: Science or Art? In: Isabelle G, Gideon D, Vincent L, Graham T, Daniel S, editors. Proceedings of ICML Workshop on Unsupervised and Transfer Learning; Proceedings of Machine Learning Research: PMLR; 2012. p. 65--79.

Peel L, Larremore DB, Clauset A. The ground truth about metadata and community detection in networks. Science Advances. 2017;3(5):e1602548.